# Freemarker - lack of special character in email subject template cause email content crash

Tags: java, spring, email, encoding, freemarker

im fighting with strange error. Im using seperate freemarker templates for mail subject and body. It is sent using org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender. Only templates that contains some special swedish character works in my application ( yes you read right... not the other way). If I delete it my email content crashes. It contains then:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

..
html code here
..
```

My freemarker.properties file

```
locale=sv_SE
classic_compatible=false

number_format=
date_format=yyyy-MM-dd
time_format=HH:mm
datetime_format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm
output_encoding=UTF-8

url_escaping_charset=UTF-8

auto_import=spring.ftl as spring
auto_include=
default_encoding=UTF-8
localized_lookup=true
strict_syntax=true
whitespace_stripping=true
template_update_delay=10
```

Ive tried to convert subject file with dos2unix tool. Using 'find -bi subject.ftl' show that encoding is us-ascii. With added special character - utf-8.

This thing is suprisingly strange for me...

//SOLUTION:
use `:set bomb` and save file in vim.

Comment: Please post the template itself - without that, we won't be able to help... Or you can try appending the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the beginning of the template file. Also, can you specify the encodign when reading the template file?

Comment: template content can be simple as 'Simple content' <- this breaks my email. 'Simple content ö' works.

'file -bi subject_no.ftl' -> text/plain; charset=us-ascii
after adding ö
'file -bi subject_no.ftl'-> text/plain; charset=utf-8

Comment: @ppeterka your comment has helped me to solve my problem. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it? I simply used `:set bomb` in vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per request of @freakman, I post my comment as an answer - as it turned out to solve the problem:

Append the **[BOM (Byte Order Mark)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)** to the beginning of the template file, to ensure it is always parsed as an UTF-8 template.

For reference, the BOM for UTF-8 is:

- Hexadecimal:   `EF BB BF`
- ISO-8859-1 encoded `ï»¿`
- Java: `byte[] bom = { (byte) 0xEF, (byte) 0xBB, (byte) 0xBF};`